# Accessing out of bounds cells in a 2D array

Tags: c, arrays

I can't really see what's wrong with my check neighbors function in my game of life. It checks all the 8 neighbours then depending on the living count assigns the cell being checked to living or dead, then updates the board.

```
void check_neighbours (int board[][COL])

{

int living = 0, i, j, k, l;
int new_board[ROW][COL];

for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
    for (j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
        if ((board[i + 1 % ROW][j % COL]) == '#')
            {
                living++;
            }
        if ((board[i - 1 % ROW ][j % COL]) == '#')
            {
                living++;
            }
        if ((board[i % ROW][j + 1 % COL]) == '#')
            {
                living++;
            }
        if ((board[i % ROW][j - 1 % COL]) == '#')
            {
                living++;
            }
        if ((board[i + 1 % ROW][j + 1 % COL]) == '#')
            {
                living++;
            }
        if ((board[i - 1 % ROW ][j + 1 % COL ]) == '#')
            {
                living++;
            }
        if ((board[i + 1 % ROW ][j - 1 % COL ]) == '#')
            {
                living++;
            }
        if ((board[i - 1 % ROW ][j - 1 % COL ]) == '#')
            {
                living++;
            }
        if (living == 3)
            {
                new_board[i][j] = '#';
            }
        if (living <= 2)
            {
                new_board[i][j] = '-';
        if (living < 3)
            {
                new_board[i][j] = '-';
            }
        }
    }


for (k = 0; k < ROW; k++)                       
    {
    for (l = 0; l < COL; l++)                   
        {
            board[k][l] = new_board[k][l]; 
        }
    }      
}
}
```

edit: Added parentheses but still prints the same

Comment: Hey, you don't need brackets for a single line ;)

Comment: @Kotshi using brackets for a single line it not necessarily bad practice.

Comment: Operator % has higher precedence than operator  +

Comment: @MichaelWalz Don't you think this is annoying in that particular case?

Comment: @Kotshi no.   It's certainly less annoying than forgetting braces when you add a new line.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I you have auto-indention, you'll immediately notice, I personally put some when I don't know if I'll add some later. Yet, in that case, removing them would be nicer to the eyes I think.

Comment: Ah well, I couldn't have guessed.

Comment: Trust me I wouldn't have opted for this method of getting a photo in if I didn't have to haha.

Comment: Ref: [game of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)

Comment: Please do not destroy your question after it has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test edge conditions before doing the `living` count.

```
for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
      int living = 0;
      for (int drow = -1; drow <= 1; drow++) {
        int row = i+drow;
        if (row < 0 || row >= ROW) continue;  // over the edge
        for (int dcol = -1; dcol <= 1; dcol++) {
          int col = j+dcol; 
          if (col < 0 || col >= COL) continue;  // over the edge
          if (row==0 && col==0) continue;  
          if (board[row][col] == '#') {
            living++;
          }
        } // endfor dcol
      } // endfor drow

      // This section may need review - GOL rules are unclear in post -see below
      if (living == 3) {
        new_board[i][j] = '#';
      } 
      ...
    } // endfor j
  } // endfor i
```

If rules follow:

Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbors dies, as if caused by under-population.
Any live cell with two or three live neighbors lives on to the next generation.
Any live cell with more than three live neighbors dies, as if by over-population.
Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbors becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.

```
     #define ALIVE ('#')
     #define DEAD  ('-')
     #define POP_MIN 2
     #define POP_MAX 3
     #define POP_REPRO 3

     new_board[i][j] = board[i][j];
     if (board[i][j] == ALIVE) {
       if (living < POP_MIN) new_board[i][j] = DEAD;
       else if (living > POP_MAX) new_board[i][j] = DEAD;
     } else {
       if (living == POP_REPRO) new_board[i][j] = ALIVE;
     }
```

Comment: also should new_board[i][j] = board[i][j] be reversed? To copy the new board into the old board? If I reverse them the board doesn't update and becomes full of dead cells.

Comment: I know I already gave the correct answer so you don't have to keep helping though :)

Comment: Your method here will cause some movement but after 10000 iterations through the game a glider will just shift on the same position?

Comment: @Finlandia_C Game-of-life edge condition can be handled, as above as an edge/wall.  Alternatively, code could wrap around.  Then `if (row < 0 || row >= ROW) continue;` becomes `row %= ROW;`  Likewise for `col`.

Comment: This also doesn't work. I'm finding it hard to put the bottom piece of cod with the top piece. No brackets on the bottom bit confuses me

Comment: The bottom bit has 4 brackets `{}{}`.

Answer (score 2):

Try sticking some brackets into your math:

```
board[(i + 1) % ROW]
```

is much safer than

```
board[i + 1 % ROW]
```

Comment: But this still prints the same messed up boards unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this:

```
board[i + 1 % ROW]
```

going *out of bounds*? Try fixing these issues.

As Paul R suggested, you could use parentheses, in order to catch up with the higher precedence of `%` operator in comparison to the `+` operator. So change the code to this:

```
board[(i + 1) % ROW]
```

Assuming ROW = 5 and i = 4, you get:

> (4 + 1) % 5 = 0 // yeah!
>
> 4 + 1 % 5 = 5 // oh dear...

Comment: I thought the % ROW addition dealt with that issue? I must be wrong

Comment: Assume @Finlandia_C, you have ROW = 5, then `i` will get the value 4, so 4 + 1 % 5 = 5, which is illegal.

Comment: Hmm. So how do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Use parentheses to fix the operator precedence problem.

Comment: This doesn't fix the `(0 - 1) % ROW`-case.

Comment: Yeah I used brackets but it still prints the same boards

Comment: Parens solve array access concerns, yet does this solve code functionality issue?  Should not edge/corner cells count neighbors as if the the map wraps or have to handle edge conditions?

Comment: @EOF how do I fix that case?